# AngularJS : Running e2e tests using Karma

Tags: testing, angularjs, karma-runner, end-to-end

I want to run my Jasmine e2e tests using KarmaJS (0.9.2). I use Google Closure with AngularJS (1.0.7) on Windows 7.  When I start karma using `karma start config\karma-e2e.js` everything works fine (browser navigates to correct page) but it doesn't execute my tests (stops on 'browser navigate to').

The `config\karma-e2e.js` file:

```
basePath = '../';

frameworks = ['ng-scenario'];

files = [
  'tests/e2e/**/*.js'
];

autoWatch = true;

singleRun = false;

browsers = ['Chrome'];

urlRoot = '/__karma/';

proxies = {
    '/': 'http://localhost:8080/'
}

plugins = [
    'karma-ng-scenario'
    'karma-chrome-launcher'
]
```

Test source (`tests\e2e\scenarios.coffee`) is:

```
describe 'Intro page view', ->

  it 'has hello world message', ->
    browser().navigateTo '/app/client/'
    expect(element('#text').text()).toBe 'Hello World'
```

I'm using html5Mode routes, angular is bootstraped manualy using `angular.bootstrap`, all my coffee scripts are compiled by IDE and I see no errors in browser console or command line. So how should I do it? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this problem. Seems angular scenario needs ng-app directive which is at least weird (or it's a bug).  So I added ng-app attribute to body after calling App.bootstrap() on index page. Everything works fine now.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
App.bootstrap();
document.body.setAttribute('ng-app', 'App');
</script>
```

Comment: +1 I just spent an hour trying to figure out why tests weren't completing.

Comment: Correct. "ngScenario does not work with apps that manually bootstrap using angular.bootstrap. You must use the ng-app directive." - http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing way down at the bottom, just before the comments.